# Please help me solve my Java homework about arrays

Tags: java, arrays

**Problem Statement:**

> Given an array of ints, compute if the array contains somewhere a value followed in the array by that value times 10. We'll use the convention of considering only the part of the array that begins at the given index.The initial call will pass in index as 0.

**Examples:**

`public boolean array220(int[] nums, int index)`

> array220({1, 2, 20}, 0) → true
>   array220({3, 30}, 0) → true
>   array220({3}, 0) → false**

I'm stuck with the problem with no approach to solve it.

Comment: If this is homework please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Do you know how to use an array and iterate through it?

Comment: More than glad to help but you should make some attempts. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry matthew,I was confused with the wordings in the paragraph hence i posted it here.i did not know how to approach it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = index; i < nums.length - 1; i++) 
    if (nums[i] * 10 == nums[i + 1]) return true;
return false;
```

Comment: @Carl What is the point if he doesn't have to work through the problem?

Comment: @Matthew If he is so far away from a solution, a clear simple worked solution probably does more to advance his understanding than a treatise.  I don't think the OP is yet ready to learn, and an elaborate explanation for a terribly simple problem might lead him to think this is hard.  It isn't hard, and knowing that is worth more (in my estimation) right now than exposure to the details of what he needs to learn.

Comment: @Carl I will meet you halfway in that sometimes when you are so far off in programming ... the only way to ever learn is to simply start with seeing solutions to problems. However, we really can't be sure how much the OP knows or doesn't know. Just saying that we should take care with throwing out solutions. We may ruin an opportunity to solve a problem IMO.

Comment: @Carl,Thanks for the solution,but it fails for one case.`array220({20, 2, 21}, 0) → false` but im getting `true` which is wrong\incorrect

Comment: @Carl, @Deepak, This is most likely a rounding issue, I would opt for multiplication instead of division.

Comment: @Shaded Thanks for the correction; updated with your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Carl for the immediate reply

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you some psuedo code to work with.

```
Let `nums` be my array

Let `i` be the starting index

Let `index` be `i + 1`

for all indices < array's length, iterate

   Let currNum be `array[index - 1]`

   if currNum times 10 equals `array[index]`
      return true

   increment index

return false because we found no numbers that we true
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you the answer as a Java program, since a number of folks have already done that.

When in doubt, try writing out the program in English (or any other native tongue). If you can't write it out in complete detail, write out what you *can*, and then refine in pieces.

> Given an array of ints, compute if the array contains somewhere a value followed in the array by that value times 10. We'll use the convention of considering only the part of the array that begins at the given index.The initial call will pass in index as 0.

What do we know here? We have an array and a starting index. So, what do you want to do? Maybe that's a bit complicated, so if we were doing it by hand, how would you start?

1. Look at the first element of the array (where "first" is the starting index)
2. Look at the next element of the array and divide it by 10
3. Look at the results from steps #1 and #2. Are they the same?

   - If they are, return true
   - If they are not, start back again at step #1, but look at the following elements instead

Then refine that further:

1. Set the current index to be the starting index
2. For each element of the array, from the current index through the end:

   1. Get the following element and divide by 10
   2. Are the two numbers equal? If so, we're done, return true
   3. If not, increment the current index and repeat

You may notice that there is a small issue with step #2: You don't want to loop *all* the way to the end. Because if you do that, there won't be any "next" element to compare it to. So really you want to loop to the second-to-last element.

Continue refining. At some point you can translate directly to Java or whatever programming language you want. (If you can't do this last step, you need to add an additional step 0: Learn the programming language first)

Answer (score -1):

Recursive answer just for the hell of it... also I wouldn't post this is there weren't already valid answers. Make an attempt and post what you tried.

```
public boolean array220(int[] nums, int index){
    if(index >= nums.length - 1)
        return false;
    if(nums[index] * 10 == nums[index + 1]){
        return true;
    } else {
        return array220(nums, ++index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Was there a problem with my answer, or did I just get downvoted for answering?

Comment: @Deepak, Ahh you were right, I didn't test it. Error has been corrected in answer.