# Design a method that takes an Array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Design a method `M4` that takes an array `A` of doubles and a double value `d`, and returns true if `d` is not found in `A` and false if `d` is found in `A`

Example:

```
`M49({1.0, 4.5, 7.7, 0.3, 2.1},7.7)`//should return false
```

Comment: Did you try anything? or searched for anything?

Comment: You can solve your problem by following this SO link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test if an array contains a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please help me solve my Java homework about arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5502927/3919155)

Answer (score 2):

You need only a simple `notContains` function?

**Java 7+:**

```
private boolean notContains(final double[] array, final double n) {
    for (double x : array) {
        if (x == n) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Java 8+** using the [Streams API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html):

```
private boolean notContains(final double[] array, final double n) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).noneMatch(x -> x == n);
}
```

Usage:

```
final double[] array = {1.0, 4.5, 7.7, 0.3, 2.1};
System.out.println("Result is: " + notContains(array, 7.7)); // ==> false
System.out.println("Result is: " + notContains(array, 7.2)); // ==> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is correct. you can also use variable length arguments(...) for your purpose but one restriction this type of parameter is last in method.

```
public static boolean notFind(double n,double ...arr){
    for(double d:arr){
        if(d==n)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And its usages

```
double[] array = {1.0, 4.5, 7.7, 0.3, 2.1};
    System.out.println(notFind(7.7, array)); //false
    System.out.println(notFind(7.2, array)); //true
```